# Calling this.refs.component.function

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

So i have a navigation component at a higher level like this:

```
<Navigation ref="nav">
<Children>
<Footer>
```

In one of my children components I want to call a method inside my Navigation component. How would I do so? I gave this a shot:

if Navigation has a method called

```
toggle() {
   this.setState({open: true})
}
```

could I call it like this in the children component?

Children:

```
openSomething = () => {
   console.log(this.refs);
   this.refs.nav.toggle();
}

<Somebutton onClick={openSomething} name="OpenStuff" />
```

After i had done this, refs had come out undefined, so I wasn't sure how to go about this. The idea is that i have a child component that I want to open a modal on button click, but it is its child and I thought of doing it this way, however it didnt work.

Comment: How the components are organized? Parents can access to children using refs. The opposite is not possibile.

Comment: Actually what if it isnt a child, what if they are just neighboring components like this : <Navigation ref ="nav"/> <BodyPage/>

Comment: If they are just neighbors they cannot communicate with refs. Ref works only from fathers to children.
That's another reason to move the entire architeture to a more functional approach using props and rendering.

Comment: Alright, I ended up refactoring it anyways. But here was a example of it done: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/app/components/master.jsx  @line259

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this from Children because Navigation is its sibling. Only their parent can refer to Navigation via `refs`. You can trigger an event from Children which is handled by the parent:

```
<Somebutton onClick={this.props.onOpen} name="OpenStuff" />
```

And then handle it in the parent component:

```
render() {
  return (
     <div>
       <Navigation ref="nav" />
       <Children onOpen={() => this.handleOnOpen()} />
     </div>
  )
}
handleOnOpen() {
   this.refs.nav.toggle()
}
```